# Change openid icon

Tags: support, openid

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I don't see it here...how do I change my user icon?  I assume it's associated with OpenID.

Comment: Looks like you got it working ` :)`

Comment: Yup.  Thanks.  I am now empowered to answer all questions with Gravitudinous impunity!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SO uses [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/).  You need to go there to change it.

Just make sure that you use the same email on the StackOverflow site and Gravatar.

There is a link to change your picture in the 'edit profile' page as well.  It takes you to the same place as my link.

Comment: Chris...thanks for cleaning up my suck.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile. Click the edit button. Click on the "change picture" link below your current icon.